# Places API (HERE) limited to only 20 entries? Loading more possible?

Tags: here-api

I'm using this [API](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/topics/quick-start-find-text-string.html) from HERE to get accommodations. Unfortunately I only get a maximum of 20 hotels back. Is it possible to get more results?

I didn't find anything in the documentation and I tried without success to add a "limit" filter. 
This is the request (I had to delete my app id and the app code):

https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/search?app_id=APP_ID&app_code=APP_CODE&in=-102.65625,-73.71566303112276,102.03125238418579,74.2119976769519&pretty&q=accommodation

It would be great to know a way how to get more than 20 results. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Places API is designed with an end user customer perspective and provides only a limited number of results for a given category. Still for any given category you will be able to get 100 results(maximum). You have to set size parameter in your request.

The below example query provides 30 results.

```
http://places.demo.api.here.com/places/v1/discover/around?at=52.521%2C13.3807&cat=hotel&size=30&Accept-Language=en-US%2Cen%3Bq%3D0.5&app_id=xxx&app_code=xxxx
```

If you need more then contact Here sales team (selfservesupport@here.com) if you need all available places of a particular business. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!